# algebras for extensions of FO and existential SO

Tags: abstract-algebra, first-order-logic, model-theory, algebraic-logic, descriptive-complexity

As cylindric algebra is the algebraization of FO with equality: How can be this algebra extended s.t. ESO is captured by it, e.g. how to algebraize quantifications of relation variables?

How can one define algebras for extensions of FO like inclusion logic FO$(\subseteq)$ or exclusion logic FO$(|)$. As FO$(\subseteq, |)$ captures ESO, it would be interesting to compare their algebras. Is there any research about that?

ESO: only existential quantifications of relation variables are allowed.

Comment: What is "ESO" - is it full second-order logic, or just a fragment? FWIW, given the complexity of second-order logic (e.g. its set of validities is extremely complicated, and SOL is not set-theoretically absolute) I suspect that algebraic analyses don't really work well for it. As a data point, googling "algebraic second-order logic" (with quotes) yields no results.

Comment: ESO is for existential second order logic and we might only consider the relational fragment (thus the fragment of SO that captures NP according to Fagins Theorem).

Comment: "SOL is not set-theoretically absolute"+1. Could you give a reference or explain why that holds? Maybe that is also valid for the relational fragment of ESO?